# Moodle: Custom SQL in SQL report shows blank page

Tags: php, moodle

I am new to moodle. I have added Configuring reports plugin, and I am trying to create sql report using it referring to this link : https://docs.moodle.org/27/en/Configurable_reports
But it shows a blank page instead of Custom SQL page as in the steps. I don't know where I am going wrong. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on debugging ( http://docs.moodle.org/en/Debugging ) to display the full error message.